# page blinks when loading

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I trying to view some html page, before the page is fully loaded I was able to see some blink page, how can I stop the browser from full load that I can view the blink page?

I am using chrome, thanks

Comment: I don't think that is possible, might have to do with your <script> files being on the top of the page instead of all the way at the bottom. Place your CSS files at the top of your page in <head>.

This is also the wrong way to ask a question, which is likely to get closed without more information or something to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I don't know what you talk about... I found what I was needed F12>source>Pausing script execution or F8. Cheers. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found how to do so, on chrome just do the following F12>source>Pausing script execution or F8. this will stop the page from full loading and load it step by step that allow you to view all that going on at the background

Cheers
Thanks